# Web browser without disk cache

Tags: linux, web-browser, caching

I'm **looking for any web browser that doesn't have** **a disk cache,** instead, **which** **keeps all data in RAM**. Preferably a minimalistic browser, but any that doesn't have a disk cache will do. It has to run on **Linux**.

Comment: So, the cache should be emptied when closing the browser, or should it save the cache on the disk when closing, and load it into the RAM when starting it again?

Comment: Preferably no cache at all, everything in RAM, and nothing saved on the disk ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Firefox

1. Open `about:config`
2. Set `browser.cache.disk.enable` to false
3. Set `browser.cache.memory.enable` to true
4. Give some more space to memory cache if you like (defaults to 32M):
   Create a new Integer entry `browser.cache.memory.capacity` if not already available and enter e.g. `131072` to give 128M.
5. Verify settings at `about:cache`